# Создание undo/rendo в createjs/easel.js

Tags: javascript

Делаю 2d редактор на canvas с помощью createjs/easeljs и встал вопрос о кнопках отменить/вернуть/повторить
Как реализовать данные действия с дочерними элементами контейнера? Что бы применялись или отменялись все изменения с каким либо дочерним элементом.
Мучаюсь уже неделю с этим! Правильного рабочего метода не нашел!

Comment: Я хранил параллельно дереву DOM некий объект с такой же древовидной структурой, который хранит все настройки каждого элемента управления и по сути является управляющим. То есть, все изменения в каждом отдельном селект-инпут и т.д. отражаются на объекте, а он уже меняет нужные элементы управления в соответствии с изменившейся внутренней структурой. Благодаря этому можно хранить этот объект в виде JSON, восстанавливать и приводить приложение в любой вид, сохранять результаты, загружать разные решения и т.д.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, а можете кинуть пример такого хранения?

Comment: Боюсь, это будет пример на уровне маленькой, но экосистемы. Долго разбираться придется в десятках файлов. А так в любой библиотеке на основе веб-компонентов (React, Angular, Vue) примеров куча, можно и без библиотек вопрос решить.

Comment: ссылки битые :(

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-undo-redo https://redux.js.org/recipes/implementing-undo-history

Comment: спасибо, буду читать